# Qt QGraphicsScene transforming selected item

Tags: c++, image, qt, math, graphics

I have a Qt application for creating some composite graphic pictures purpose. E.g. user selects some image component from the toolbar, places it on the `QGraphicsScene`, transforms it and gets profit.

**The question is:** how to perform *scale* and *rotation* operations on the selected items.

For now i have inherited my own `Scene` class and using this code for `mouseMoveEvent`:

```
void Scene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *evt)
{
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(evt);

    //bool isLMB = QApplication::mouseButtons() & Qt::LeftButton;

    bool isShift = QApplication::keyboardModifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier;
    bool isCtrl = QApplication::keyboardModifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier;

    if (this->newChip)
    {
        qreal ox = this->newChip->pos().x();
        qreal oy = this->newChip->pos().y();

        qreal nx = evt->scenePos().x();
        qreal ny = evt->scenePos().y();

        qreal dx = nx - ox;
        qreal dy = ny - oy;

        qreal w = this->newChip->transform().m11() * this->newChip->boundingRect().width();
        qreal h = this->newChip->transform().m22() * this->newChip->boundingRect().height();

        qreal l = sqrt(pow((float) dx, (float) 2.f) + pow((float) dy, (float) 2.f));

        if (!isShift && !isCtrl)
        {
            this->newChip->setPos(evt->scenePos());
        }

        if (isShift)
        {
            //this->newChip->scale(fabs(w / dx), fabs(h / dy));

            qDebug() << "scale: " << dx / w << dy / h;
        }

        if (isCtrl)
        {
            //this->newChip->rotate((qreal) (acos((float) (dx / l)) * 180.f / 3.14f));

            qDebug() << "rotate: " << acos((float) (dx / l)) * 180.f / 3.14f;
        }
    }
}
```

But i do want a more pretty rotation and scale operations, just like any painting software when operating a selection, for example:

[image]

**P.S.:** yeah, i've started modifying the [`40000 chips`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.3/demos-chip.html) demo application =)

Comment: You seem to ask a question and then display code that answers it, does it not work?

Comment: No, maths logic for rotation is too rough so item just crazily spins in one direction. And scaling does not work at all. While manipulating via <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys is ugly too. The screen shows the nice implementation example.

Comment: Rotation only goes in one direction because calling QGraphicsItem::rotate() doesn't set the angle of the overall angle, it merely rotates the QGraphicsItem in addition to however much it's already been rotated. If you want to set the overall angle, you should use `QGraphicsItem->setTransform->QTransform().rotate(angle)`.

Comment: @Anthony Should be `graphicsItem->setTransform(QTransform().rotate(angle))`, to be precise.